# replaceAll not working when removing carriage returns

Tags: java, regex

I am using this call to remove carriage returns from a String

```
input = input.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");
return input;
```

But when given this String as input: `http://localhost:4200/\n\rhome`

I get the following output: `http://localhost:4200/\\n\\rhome`

Any idea why? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Probably, your input string has no line breaks at all, try `input.replaceAll("\\\\[rn]", "");`

Comment: cant get optuput as say. usually tell regex control code notation `"[\\r\\n]"` not the actual code as translated by java. `"[\r\n]"`